# как завершить процессы досрочно т.е до того, как он полностью выполнит функцию?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Вопрос связан с работой модуля Multiprocessing. Я создал несколько процессов с помощью multiprocessing.Process. В этих процессах параллельно выполняются несколько функций. Вопрос: как завершить процессы досрочно т.е до того, как он полностью выполнит функцию?

Comment: Кажется, никак.

Comment: [os.kill](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html)

Answer (score 1):

```py
import multiprocessing
import time
def Child_process():
   print ('Starting function')
   time.sleep(5)
   print ('Finished function')
P = multiprocessing.Process(target = Child_process)
P.start()
print("My Process has terminated, terminating main thread")
print("Terminating Child Process")
P.terminate()
print("Child Process successfully terminated")
```

Comment: Но хорошо бы кроме кода давать и пояснительный текст, хотя бы вкратце - в чём суть вашего кода.

Comment: полностью согласен с вами, коллега

Comment: Часто код говорит сам за себя, я думал в этом примере так и есть. Мы запускаем код и видим как и что меняется. Не стоит искать полного разжевывания каждой строчки кода. Над каждой задачей нужно думать самому и только тогда вы сможете развиваться. Подумайте над каждой строчкой кода, грубо говоря тут всего лишь 3 строчки кода над которыми нужно подумать и чтобы выполнить задачу и понять суть этого кода, прочитайте https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html, также нужно понимать что такое процесс в операционной системе, как процессы взаимодействуют между собой

Comment: У вас также может быть главный процесс, который управляет процессами воркерами и убивает их. Например когда главному процессу(родителю) приходит сообщение от порожденного процесса(ребенка) например через Queue, то главный процесс убивает child process